# Look through the last 15 lines of a log file to check for "error" repeated 3 times and execute a command

Tags: parsing, unix, text, logfile

I would like a script that would read the last 15 lines of a text file and if the word "error" appears more than 3 times it would execute a command.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `tail -15 <file> | grep error | wc -l` -gt 3 ]
then
   echo "Too many errors..."
else
   echo "Everything is fine."
fi
```

Or on the command line:

```
if [ `tail -15 <file> | grep error | wc -l` -gt 3 ]; then echo "Too many errors..."; else echo "Everything is fine."; fi
```